# DataStax Enterprise on Docker: fails to start due to /hadoop/conf directory not being writable

Tags: bash, hadoop, docker, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I've followed [DataStax's guide on best practices for using DSE with Docker](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/resources/DataStax-WP-Best_Practices_Running_DSE_Within_Docker.pdf), but I've run into the following bug using all of the default setup scripts and Dockerfiles provided by DataStax.

### Error Log

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to save custom DSE Hadoop config
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.writeDseHadoopConfig(CassandraJobConf.java:310) ~[dse-hadoop-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.writeDseHadoopConfig(CassandraJobConf.java:174) ~[dse-hadoop-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.ConfigurationWriterPlugin.onActivate(ConfigurationWriterPlugin.java:20) ~[dse-hadoop-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.initialize(PluginManager.java:377) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.activateDirect(PluginManager.java:306) ~[dse-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Directory not writable: /opt/dse/resources/hadoop/conf
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.saveConfiguration(CassandraJobConf.java:466) ~[dse-hadoop-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.saveDseHadoopConfiguration(CassandraJobConf.java:345) ~[dse-hadoop-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.writeDseHadoopConfig(CassandraJobConf.java:300) ~[dse-hadoop-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Unable to start DSE server: Unable to activate plugin com.datastax.bdp.ConfigurationWriterPlugin
com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager$PluginActivationException: Unable to activate plugin com.datastax.bdp.ConfigurationWriterPlugin
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.activateDirect(PluginManager.java:327)
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.activate(PluginManager.java:259)
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.activate(PluginManager.java:169)
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.preStart(PluginManager.java:77)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preStart(DseDaemon.java:490)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.start(DseDaemon.java:462)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:583)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to save custom DSE Hadoop config
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.writeDseHadoopConfig(CassandraJobConf.java:310)
        at com.datastax.bdp.hadoop.mapred.CassandraJobConf.writeDseHadoopConfig(CassandraJobConf.java:174)
        at com.datastax.bdp.ConfigurationWriterPlugin.onActivate(ConfigurationWriterPlugin.java:20)
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.initialize(PluginManager.java:377)
        at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.activateDirect(PluginManager.java:306)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Directory not writable: /opt/dse/resources/hadoop/conf
```

Error is pretty straight forward, tried to address it by adding some additional `chmod` calls in the `Dockerfile` to no avail.

### Dockerfile

```
# Provided without any warranty, these files are intended
# to accompany the whitepaper about DSE on Docker and are
# not intended for production and are not actively maintained.

# Loosely based on docker-cassandra by the fine folk at Spotify
# -- https://github.com/spotify/docker-cassandra/
# Loosely based on cassandra-docker by the one and only Al Tobey
# -- https://github.com/tobert/cassandra-docker/

# base yourself on any ubuntu 14.04 image containing JDK8
# official Docker Java images are distributed with OpenJDK
# Datastax certifies its product releases specifically
# on the Oracle/Sun JVM, so YMMV with OpenJDK

FROM nimmis/java:oracle-8-jdk

# Avoid ERROR: invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install adduser \
    curl \
    lsb-base \
    procps \
    zlib1g \
    gzip \
    python \
    python-support \
    sysstat \
    ntp bash tree && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
RUN curl -o /bin/gosu -SkL "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.4/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && chmod +x /bin/gosu


# DSE tarball can be download into the folder where Dockerfile is
# wget --user=$USER --password=$PASS http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/dse-5.0.0-bin.tar.gz
# you may want to replace dse-5.0.0-bin.tar.gz with the corresponding downloaded package name. When
# downloaded, please remove the version number part of the filename (or create a symlink), so the
# resulting file is named dse-bin.tar.gz (that way the docker file itself remains version independent).
#
# DataStax Agent debian package can be downloaded from
# wget --user=$USER --password=$PASS http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/pool/datastax-agent_6.0.0_all.deb
# you may want to replace the specific version with the corresponding downloaded package name. When
# downloaded, please remove the version number part of the filename (or create a symlink), so the
# resulting file is named datastax-agent_all.deb (that way the docker file itself remains version
# independent).
ADD dse.tar.gz /opt
ADD datastax-agent_all.deb /tmp

ENV DSE_HOME /opt/dse

RUN ln -s /opt/dse* $DSE_HOME

# keep data here
VOLUME /data

# and logs here
VOLUME /logs

VOLUME /opt/dse

# create a dedicated user for running DSE node
RUN groupadd -g 1337 cassandra && \
    useradd -u 1337 -g cassandra -s /bin/bash -d $DSE_HOME cassandra && \
    chown -R cassandra:cassandra /opt/dse* 

RUN chmod r+w -R /opt/dse/

# install the agent
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/datastax-agent_all.deb

# starting node using custom entrypoint that configures paths, interfaces, etc.
COPY scripts/dse-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dse-entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/dse-entrypoint"]

# Running any other DSE/C* command should be done on behalf dse user
# Perform that using a generic command laucher
COPY scripts/dse-cmd-launcher /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dse-cmd-launcher

# link dse commands to the launcher
RUN for cmd in cqlsh dsetool nodetool dse cassandra-stress; do \
        ln -sf /usr/local/bin/dse-cmd-launcher /usr/local/bin/$cmd ; \
    done

# the detailed list of ports
# http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfFirePort.html

# Cassandra
EXPOSE 7000 9042 9160

# Solr
EXPOSE 8983 8984

# Spark
EXPOSE 4040 7080 7081 7077

# Hadoop
EXPOSE 8012 50030 50060 9290

# Hive/Shark
EXPOSE 10000

# Graph
```

The last place where there might be an answer to fixing this issue might be the startup script used to actually launch DSE when this container starts.

### DSE Startup Script (Called by Docker container on startup)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Provided without any warranty, these files are intended
# to accompany the whitepaper about DSE on Docker and are 
# not intended for production and are not actively maintained.

# Bind the various services
# These should be updated on every container start

if [ -z ${IP} ]; then
  IP=`hostname --ip-address`
fi

echo $IP > /data/ip.address

# create directories for holding the node's data, logs, etc.
create_dirs() {
  local base_dir=$1;

  mkdir -p $base_dir/data/commitlog
  mkdir -p $base_dir/data/saved_caches
  mkdir -p $base_dir/data/hints
  mkdir -p $base_dir/logs
}

# tweak the cassandra config
tweak_cassandra_config() {
  env="$1/cassandra-env.sh"
  conf="$1/cassandra.yaml"

  base_data_dir="/data"

  # Set the cluster name
  if [ -z "${CLUSTER_NAME}" ]; then
    printf " - No cluster name provided; skipping.\n"
  else
    printf " - Setting up the cluster name: ${CLUSTER_NAME}\n"
    regexp="s/Test Cluster/${CLUSTER_NAME}/g"
    sed -i -- "$regexp" $conf
  fi

  # Set the commitlog directory, and various other directories
  # These are done only once since the regexep matches will fail on subsequent
  # runs.
  printf " - Setting up directories\n"
  regexp="s|/var/lib/cassandra/|$base_data_dir/|g"
  sed -i -- "$regexp" $conf
  regexp="s/^listen_address:.*/listen_address: ${IP}/g"
  sed -i -- "$regexp" $conf
  regexp="s/rpc_address:.*/rpc_address: ${IP}/g"
  sed -i -- "$regexp" $conf

  # seeds
  if [ -z "${SEEDS}" ]; then
    printf " - Using own IP address ${IP} as seed.\n";
    regexp="s/seeds:.*/seeds: \"${IP}\"/g";
  else
    printf " - Using seeds: $SEEDS\n";
    regexp="s/seeds:.*/seeds: \"${IP},${SEEDS}\"/g"
  fi
  sed -i -- "$regexp" $conf

  # JMX
  echo "JVM_OPTS=\"\$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1\"" >> $env
}

tweak_dse_in_sh() {
  # point C* logs dir to the created volume
  sed -i -- "s|/var/log/cassandra|/logs|g" "$1/dse.in.sh"
}

tweak_spark_config() {
  sed -i -- "s|/var/lib/spark/|/data/spark/|g" "$1/spark-env.sh"
  sed -i -- "s|/var/log/spark/|/logs/spark/|g" "$1/spark-env.sh"
  mkdir -p /data/spark/worker
  mkdir -p /data/spark/rdd
  mkdir -p /logs/spark/worker
}

tweak_agent_config() {
  [ -d "/var/lib/datastax-agent" ] && cat > /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml <<EOF
stomp_interface: ${STOMP_INTERFACE}
use_ssl: 0
local_interface: ${IP}
hosts: ["${IP}"]
cassandra_install_location: /opt/dse
cassandra_log_location: /logs
EOF
  chown cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
}

setup_node() {
  printf "* Setting up node...\n"
  printf " + Setting up node...\n"

  create_dirs
  tweak_cassandra_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/cassandra/conf"
  tweak_dse_in_sh "$DSE_HOME/bin"
  tweak_spark_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/spark/conf"
  tweak_agent_config
  chown -R cassandra:cassandra /data /logs /conf

  # mark that we tweaked configs
  touch "$DSE_HOME/tweaked_configs"

  printf "Done.\n"
}

# if marker file doesn't exist, setup node
[ ! -f "$DSE_HOME/tweaked_configs" ] && setup_node

[ -f "/etc/init.d/datastax-agent" ] && /etc/init.d/datastax-agent start

exec gosu cassandra "$DSE_HOME/bin/dse" cassandra -f "$@"
```

### Docker Container Commandline Arguments

And here's the commandline arguments I'm using to launch a single DSE instance via Docker:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Used to start a single DSE node that has both Spark and Cassandra running on it
OPSC_CONTAINER=$1

if [ -z "$OPSC_CONTAINER" ]; then
  echo "usage: start_docker_cluster.sh OPSCContainerName"
  echo "  OPSCContainerName   mandatory name of the container running OpsCenter"
  exit 1
fi

[ -z "$CLUSTER_NAME" ] && CLUSTER_NAME="Test_Cluster"

STOMP_INTERFACE=`docker exec $OPSC_CONTAINER hostname -I`
docker run -p 7080:7080 -p 4040:4040 -p 7077:7077 -p 9042:9042 --link $OPSC_CONTAINER -d -e CLUSTER_NAME="$CLUSTER_NAME" -e STOMP_INTERFACE="$STOMP_INTERFACE" --name dse dse -k -t
```

The `-k -t` flags [indicate that we're going to be launching both Hadoop and Spark for this container](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/startStop/refDseStandalone.html). I've dropped the `-t` flag and still had this configuraiton error occur even without it.

*What do I need to do to make the `/opt/dse/resources/hadoop/conf` directory writable so DSE can successfully boot?*

Answer (score 2):

Adding 'chown -RHh cassandra:cassandra /opt/dse' to the entrypoint script solved my problem of not being able to write to  /opt/dse/resources/hadoop/conf.

Re. ERROR 04:15:04,789 SPARK-WORKER Logging.scala:74 - Failed to create work directory /var/lib/spark/worker

Check your **spark-env.sh**, and see your directory mappings. In my case, i have mounted two external volumes - /data and /logs. Both these directories are owned by cassandra:cassandra.

```
# This is a base directory for Spark Worker work files.
if [ "x$SPARK_WORKER_DIR" = "x" ]; then
    export SPARK_WORKER_DIR="/data/spark/worker"
fi

if [ "x$SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS" = "x" ]; then
    export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS="/data/spark/rdd"
fi

# This is a base directory for Spark Worker logs.
if [ "x$SPARK_WORKER_LOG_DIR" = "x" ]; then
   export SPARK_WORKER_LOG_DIR="/logs/spark/worker"
fi

# This is a base directory for Spark Master logs.
if [ "x$SPARK_MASTER_LOG_DIR" = "x" ]; then
   export SPARK_MASTER_LOG_DIR="/logs/spark/master"
fi
```

This video shows fully functional DSE Enterprise running on docker: https://vimeo.com/181393134

Answer (score 1):

I added `chown -RHh cassandra:cassandra /opt/dse` in the `setup_node()` portion of **DSE Startup Script (Called by Docker container on startup)** and it fixed the issue. Check out `chown --help` for more info on those options.

> NOTE: I'm now getting a `ERROR 04:15:04,789 SPARK-WORKER Logging.scala:74 - Failed to create work directory /var/lib/spark/worker` later on, but at least my fix will get you past your initial issue.

```
setup_node() {
  printf "* Setting up node...\n"
  printf " + Setting up node...\n"

  create_dirs
  tweak_cassandra_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/cassandra/conf"
  tweak_dse_in_sh "$DSE_HOME/bin"
  tweak_spark_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/spark/conf"
  tweak_agent_config
  tweak_dse_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/dse/conf"
  chown -R cassandra:cassandra /data /logs /conf

  chown -RHh cassandra:cassandra /opt/dse

  # mark that we tweaked configs
  touch "$DSE_HOME/tweaked_configs"

  printf "Done.\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

> I added chown -RHh cassandra:cassandra /opt/dse in the setup_node() portion of DSE Startup Script (Called by Docker container on startup)

as answered by Max worked for me, but instead of his issue I got

```
Unable to activate plugin com.datastax.bdp.plugin.DseFsPlugin
(...)
java.io.IOException: Failed to create work directory: /var/lib/dsefs
```

So I had to turn my setup_node() to this

```
setup_node() {
  printf "* Setting up node...\n"
  printf " + Setting up node...\n"

  create_dirs
  tweak_cassandra_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/cassandra/conf"
  tweak_dse_in_sh "$DSE_HOME/bin"
  tweak_spark_config "$DSE_HOME/resources/spark/conf"
  tweak_agent_config
  chown -R cassandra:cassandra /data /logs /conf

  mkdir /var/lib/dsefs
  chown -RHh cassandra:cassandra /opt/dse /var/lib/dsefs

  # mark that we tweaked configs
  touch "$DSE_HOME/tweaked_configs"

  printf "Done.\n"
}
```